# Can't get calculated column syntax right

Tags: column, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, syntax

This "ought" to be easy and yet as with so many things SharePoint, it isn't. I have a calculated column where I keep getting a syntax error. If the user sets a dropdown column value to x, then y should be Text.

Course # is the drop down field Course Name is the field I'm trying to get to calculate

```
=IF([Course #]="AWR135"
    ,"Promoting Community Cybersecurity Planning"
    ,=IF([Course #]="AWR136"
          ,"Essentials of Community Cybersecurity"
        )
   )
```

There are actually 2 more classes but that's plenty for now. If I use this formula, then I get the syntax error. If I use just one of the conditions then It saves, but nothing returns in the field for the Course Name.

I need to do this in another column where the I want the setting the course number fills in the correct project number. I could create a document or a list that has the course information but, then how do I set up the column to pull the right value from that list?

Answer (score 4):

I reformatted the Formula in your original post, you can copy/paste multilines and SharePoint will ignore them.

The **=** was allready spotted;

You are also missing a *False* in your second IF

```
=IF([Course #]="AWR135"
    ,"Promoting Community Cybersecurity Planning"
    ,IF([Course #]="AWR136"
        ,"Essentials of Community Cybersecurity"
        ,""
       )
   )
```

Should paste without errors

Comment: You covered both issues, so I deleted my answer. I didn't notice the missing else portion.

Comment: Well to be 100% complete, a missing False statement is no error, the Formula will work. But will return a *No/False* value for the False statement by default

Comment: SUCCESS! Ya'll rock.

Comment: Cool! And that in the midst of my mid-life crisis! Now go mark any of the answers as Answered and keep StackOverflow clean

Answer (score 1):

below formula should work for you

Try this:

=IF([Course#]="AWR136","Promoting Community Cybersecurity Planning",IF([Course#]="AWR135","Essentials of Community Cybersecurity"))

[image]